# Adjacent non-coprime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Are there any adjacent pairs of numbers that are not coprime? If so, what are they? If not, is there a proof for this, and what is it. From ordinary thought it seems like there aren't but is there an incredibly large pair. By adjacent I mean integers with a distance of 1 from each of.

Comment: $$(n,n+1)=(n,1)=\cdots$$

Comment: If so, then Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes could fail! $\ $

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "adjacent pairs of numbers"? Is your question talking about two pairs of numbers that are somehow adjacent, or just one pair of numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any number which is a factor of both $n$ and $n+1$ will also be a factor of their difference ($=1$). So they will be co-prime.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's Algorithm quickly shows there aren't.
$\gcd(x,x+1) = \gcd(x,1) = 1$.